# Bash %d starts with 0, can I make it start with 1

Tags: imagemagick

I'm using python and have the following command.

```
subprocess.Popen(['convert '+document+' '+outFile+'_page%04d.tif'],
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).wait()
```

It works fine, except I end up with my output as XXX_page0000.tif as my first page, then numbering up.

Is it possible to get the %04d in bash to start at 1 instead of 0.

So that my first output file is XXX_page0001.tif ?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with `bash`.  The `%d` is something handled by the `convert` program.

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%d` is not handled by `bash`, its handled by imagemagicks `convert`.

You can specify the starting number using `-scene`, so you could do:

```
subprocess.Popen(['convert -scene 1 '+document+' '+outFile+'_page%04d.tif'],
             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).wait()
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Good for me to learn more that this wasn't bash handling this.  Thanks again.